# QGIS: Output atlas maps with bounding box ratio but sized to a specific max width and height

Tags: qgis, atlas

I have layer outlining a series of regions I need to output in atlas. All are rectangles. Some are taller than they are wide (portrait), some are wider than they are tall (landscape).

If they are landscape, I need to set the width to 14" and adjust the height accordingly keeping the same aspect ratio of the bounding box.

If they are portrait, I need to set the height to 10" and adjust the width accordingly keeping the same aspect ratio of the bounding box.

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured this out using a series of expressions in atlas.

First, I set two layer variables:

`max_heght` and `max_width` and set these to the maximum the output can be in inches (this so I can adjust all the formulas as needed in one spot if the project needs change).

Next, I set the properties of both 'page properties' `width` and `height` as well as the map itself 'position and size' `width` and `height` to:

Width:

```
if(bounds_width(@atlas_geometry)/bounds_height(@atlas_geometry)>1,
@max_width,
@max_height * bounds_width(@atlas_geometry)/bounds_height(@atlas_geometry)
)
```

Height:

```
if(bounds_width(@atlas_geometry)/bounds_height(@atlas_geometry)>1,
@max_width * bounds_height(@atlas_geometry)/bounds_width(@atlas_geometry),
@max_height
)
```

Basically, this says:

*If it is portrait (ratio is >1) set the 'width' to the `max_width` variable, and adjust the height according to the original aspect ratio. Otherwise, set the 'height' at `max_height` and adjust the width accordingly.*